# Will all instances of ChildEventListener fire in the case of multiple server instances?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question regarding [ChildEventListener](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ChildEventListener.html). I am working on a backend API that is running on the JVM. I plan on the possibility that multiple instances of this server will be running simultaneously. If I were to subscribe to Child Events of say the "users" sub-document, would all instances of the server running the same code receive the event? If so, is there a way in which only one can consume the event?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Database broadcasts changes out to all listening clients. There is no way for one client to prevent a specific change from being sent to the other clients.

It sounds though like you're trying to create a producer/consumer queue with multiple consumers/workers. There is a library to support that sort of scenario called [`firebase-queue'](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue). It uses Firebase Database transactions to ensure only one client can *claim* the work.

It's sort of the opposite approach from what you are trying: if multiple workers *write* to claim a task, it allows only one of those writes to occur. As far as I can see this would accomplish your requirement.